# How to calculate the area of self-intersecting polygons on Earth

Tags: algorithm, polygon, area, geodesic-sphere

I am trying to find the area of self-intersecting (complex) polygons on Earth. Is there any library that implements correctly area computation for such geometries?

So far I have tried [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) and [Polygon2](https://github.com/lmoustakas/Polygon2/tree/master/src) (based on [gpc](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/)) but they give wrong results for complex polygons.

In alternative, is there a simple way to convert self-intersecting polygons into a set of simple polygons, so that I can use algorithms for simple geometries and then sum all the polygons? I know that a solution would be to implement the [Bentley-Ottman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) to find intersection points and then divide the polygon into a set of simple polygons, but if there is a library I could use I would gladly avoid reinventing the wheel (and possibly introducing bugs).

Update: The coordinates I am using do not explicit include intersection points. Therefore clipping libraries seem not to handle them properly. For example, in the following code `coords_1` and `coords_2` define the same polygon. Using Polygon2 clipping library.

```
>>> coords_1 = [(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)]
>>> coords_2 = [(0,0), (0.5, 0.5), (1,0), (1,1), (0.5,0.5), (0,1)]
>>> Polygon(coords_1).area()
0
>>> Polygon(coords_2).area()
0.5
```

I would like to get the second result, by using coords_1. I have also tried other clipping libraries but no luck so far.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how different two trajectories on Earth are by measuring the area defined by the polygon between them.

Comment: A far cry, but you may find this interesting: http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/knowledge-management-databases-and-data-mining/mobility-data-modeling-management-and-understanding (I happened to see it yesterday)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approximate solution would be to map the polygons to the plane, and use a plane geometry library to do the computational geometry. This approximation should work really well for polygons which are small relative to the entire sphere; but even for large polygons, you can be arbitrarily accurate by sufficiently refining your polygon.

I don't think there is much library functionality for intrinsically spherical operations, unfortunately.

Edit: here is a shapely solution which I think does what you want:

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import  LinearRing, Polygon

coords_1 = [(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)]
##coords_1 = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]

lr = LinearRing(coords_1)

if lr.is_valid:
    print Polygon(lr).area
else:
    print Polygon(coords_1).buffer(0).area + Polygon(coords_1[::-1]).buffer(0).area
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the problem seems to have changed, and I have updated the question accordingly. Clipping/computational geometry libraries apparently do not handle polygons with implicit intersection points. Any suggestion?

Comment: I know that python's shapely handles this kind of thing given the right commands (which is a wrapper around GEOS; not sure if you are working in python or C?)

Comment: edited the answer; implicit intersections are resolved by the buffer method; the negative area pieces get rejected in this way, so I compute them for both orientations. Seems to work, but I wonder if there isn't a better way to solve your endgoal, when taking a step back.

Comment: Thanks, this really solves the issue. I wonder too if there's a better way, but this will do for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your lat/lon polygons to play nice on the Euclidean plane. Then use something like: http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately clipping libraries do not handle polygons with implicit intersection points. I have updated the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "implicit intersection points" but nevertheless clipping libraries like Clipper (link above) can remove self intersections by a simple 'union' operation. This then allows meaningful results from area calculations.